# How to quickly fill in same ID with same value

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

Considering my table looks like that

| id | group |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | AAA |
| 123 |  |
| 123 |  |
| 231 | BBB |
| 231 | BBB |
| 312 |  |
| 312 | CC |

I would like to somehow have table looking like that

| id | group |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | AAA |
| 123 | AAA |
| 123 | AAA |
| 231 | BBB |
| 231 | BBB |
| 312 | CCC |
| 312 | CCC |

Can be DAX (calculated column), can be PowerQuery, can be SQL. Anything basically. I just would like to avoid self merge in PQ I guess? Tried with EARLIER function in DAX but had no success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously if you are using DAX then you can't overwrite the original column entries. Rather, you would need to create a new Calculated Column, using, for example:

```
=
VAR ThisID = Table1[id]
RETURN
    MINX (
        FILTER (
            Table1,
            Table1[id] = ThisID
        ),
        Table1[group]
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

A powerquery/M way

Finds all matching rows that have same ID, pulls the group column, removes nulls, returns first answer

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn( Table.RemoveColumns(Source,{"group"}),"group",(x)=>List.RemoveNulls(Table.SelectRows(Source, each [id]=x[id]) [group]){0})
in #"Added Custom"
```

or

group, then bascially the same as above, then expand. Will work more quickly then above method for large data sets

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"id"}, {
    {"data", each _, type table},
    {"group", each List.RemoveNulls(_[group]){0}}
}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"id"}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "data", {"id"}, {"id"})
in #"Expanded data"
```

Answer (score 1):

using ***SQL***

you can create a VIEW in SQL and call that view in your data model in Power BI.

```
CREATE VIEW v_table1 
AS
select t1.id, t2.[group]
from Table_1  as t1
inner join (select id, [group]  
            from Table_1
            where [group] is not null) as t2 on t1.id = t2.id
Go

select * from v_table1
```

output